# Trying to average 1 column when another column is within specific range

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find the average number of days a product was on the shelf for each month of the year, before being sold. And I need to segregate these as per the price range of the product in different columns. Expected output is like this:

```
Year | Month | 400-599 | 600-799| 800-999| Over 1000
2016 | 01    |   23    |  13    |   32   |  7
2016 | 02    |   13    |  19    |   21   | 16
```

But the below-mentioned query is NOT returning the desired results. What I am getting wrong?

```
USE DATABASE;  
GO
SELECT YEAR(datetime) AS 'YEAR', MONTH(datetime) AS 'MONTH',
CASE    WHEN price BETWEEN 400 AND 599 THEN AVG(days_on_shelf) AS '400-599',
        WHEN price BETWEEN 600 AND 799 THEN AVG(days_on_shelf) AS '600-799',
        WHEN price BETWEEN 800 AND 999 THEN AVG(days_on_shelf) AS '800-999',
        ELSE AVG(days_on_shelf) END AS 'Over 1000'
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY MONTH(datetime), YEAR(datetime), price
ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH
```

;

Comment: Post sample data too please

Comment: Each column should have its own case. e.g. `AVG(CASE WHEN price BETWEEN 400 AND 599 THEN days_on_shelf END) AS '400-599', AVG(CASE WHEN...` etc

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ZLK. It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select year(dt) as "year", month(dt) as "month",
    avg(case when price between 400 and 599 then days_on_shelf end) as "400-599",
    avg(case when price between 600 and 799 then days_on_shelf end) as "600-799",
    avg(case when price between 800 and 999 then days_on_shelf end) as "800-999",
    avg(case when price > 999 then days_on_shelf end) as "Over 1000"
from table1
group by year(dt), month(dt)
order by "year", "month";
```

It appears that `price` cannot be less that 400?

I would suggest that you read up on the documentation for `case` expressions. And as you attempted to group by `price` you could probably stand to find a good tutorial on grouping as well. It wouldn't make sense to try to group by prices yet still get results on different price ranges in the same row.

There's another approach using pivoting but that seems like overkill.

```
with a as (
    select year(dt) as "year", month(dt) as "month",
        case when price / 200 < 5 then price / 200 else 5 end as price_bucket,
        avg(days_on_shelf) as avg_days
    from t
    group by year(dt), month(dt), price / 200
)
select "year", "month",
    [2] as "400-599", [3] as "600-799", [4] as "800-999", [5] as "Over 1000"
from a pivot (min(avg_days) for price_bucket in ([2], [3], [4], [5])) p
order by "year", "month";
```

http://rextester.com/PYBR16941

Comment: Thanks, @Shawnt00. My dataset is much larger and spans at least a couple of year for 10s of products. I tried your solution but somehow, I am getting a lot of NULLs in fields whereas they all should have some value.

Comment: Any specific examples that might be insightful for use here?